# Python Pandas - how to write a string to a spcific cell via index without using the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to use pandas to write a value to a specific cell via index (1,1), in an xlsx file.
Lets say I currently have an xlsx file:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
```

How can I update 2 to another value without using the whole dataframe please?
For the pupose of what I working on, I would like to specify the value as a string via index (1,1).

Comment: Before that, do you have the opportunity to read the exel file in Dataframe completely or not? If so, then you can use df.at [1, 'B'] = 'another value' or df.loc[1, 'B'] = 'another value'.

Comment: unfortunatley, I dont.

Comment: Or, if there is any other alternative to pandas to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write to the cell using the **openpxyl** package:

#### Code:

```
import openpyxl

# Load the workbook
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("example.xlsx")

# Select the sheet you want to modify
worksheet = workbook["Sheet1"]

# Write to a specific cell
worksheet["B2"] = "Another Value"

workbook.save("example.xlsx")
```